# What does the "~" character signify at the end of a filename (linux)

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, terminal, filenames

I am repeatedly executing the `ls -l` command within `/tmp/stream` and I receive the following output:

```
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 112
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 112812 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 112
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 112812 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg~
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 116748 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg~
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 117608 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 117608 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg~
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 118674 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg~
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 118147 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 118147 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg~
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $ ls -l
total 116
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 117175 Feb  7 03:32 pic.jpg
pi@dewsaq18 /tmp/stream $

......and so on
```

My question is - what exactly is going on with the "~" character appended to the second (empty) file? Why doesn't this file show up each time `ls -l` is executed?

Since I'm using a static filename `pic.jpg` and the image is overwritten each time a new one is taken, my initial thought was the `pic.jpg~` file's use was to compare changes between frames.

However, it isn't always there (maybe there were no changes, so it is not needed?) and, even more so, it is always empty without any data written to it at all.

Thanks for the help and direction in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tilde (`~`) at the end of a file name is often used to signify a backup file. So if you have a file `foo.bar` and you edit it and save it, the new saved file would be `foo.bar` and the previous version would be `foo.bar~`. But it's program dependent: not all editors or programs would save the prior version of a file as a backup, and if they do, they don't all follow the convention of appending a tilde (`~`). It's not literally a standard, but rather a very commonly used convention.

Comment: i was about to say this should be an answer also here is an example http://office-recovery.com/excel.asp uses this for their backup files... i imagine a lot of programs follow this convention

Comment: It's common enough on linux to have an option for the `ls` command not to show them. It's `-B` or `--ignore-backups`.

Comment: @ooga indeed, it is. I agree. I only shy from the word "standard" in the sense that it hasn't been defined by any standards committee for Linux as a necessary method for naming backups.

Comment: @mbratch Good point! But re-reading the question, there's still a mystery. Why doesn't it show up every time? He seems to be doing an `ls- l` over and over and it only shows up sometimes. And when it does, it has a size of 0.

Comment: @ooga one possibility is that the backup was created but then the edit (or whatever process was occurring on the jpeg file) was aborted, leaving the original intact and an empty backup file name. A less likely possibility is that it's created as some kind of temporary working file in the same directory, abandoned before it's been filled with data (due to command abort?).